# Чем актуально делать верхнее меню сайта?

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт

Только начинаю изучать front-end, полазил посмотрел код различных сайтов в интернете и появился вопрос: в каких ситуациях стоит делать верхнее меню сайта на flex, а в каких на grid (на каких то видел и просто через inline-block), не понимаю принципиально ли это, а если так, то в каких ситуациях что лучше будет использовать

Comment: В таких, в которых один инструмент решает поставленную задачу лучше чем другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того какие браузеры вам необходимо поддерживать. Глобально нету привязки того какие именно стили вы будете применять... Grid, flex-box, float, table это в конечном счете не важно. Важно - будет ли это одинаково смотреться на всех устройствах и не отпугнет ли ваша верстка пользователя. Дальше про культуру компании, код стаил и прочую лабуду навешают...

Приведу пример - вы решили делать при помощи grid, Вы разрабатываете сайт интернет магазина по типу `Amazon`. Часть пользовалелей заходит на ваш сайт со старых мобильных `Iphone 6` и покупает там товар. Некоторые [свойства grid](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid%20) не поддерживаеться старыми браузерами и не будут. И получаеться, что выбраный вами метод для части пользователей поламает пользовательское восприятие. Они уходят с сайта -> сайт не заработал -> вы теряете работу, потому что вам плевать на людей и вообще вы хотеле сделать как проще и удобнее для Вас.

Так что - Адаптивность, однообразие во всех браузерах, скорость сборки, отсутствие лишнего.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score -3):

У любой технологии своя история и область применения. Grid — это сетка, она размечает КРУПНЫЕ области страницы, потому не подойдёт для верхнего меню. Тут flex сподручнее: на нём менюшки верстать одно удовольствие. Принципиальных отличий от inline-block нет, но логика последнего куда проще, поэтому, если ваше решение не использует специфической разметки, лучше inline-block и использовать: быстрее отобразится, поддерживается даже древними браузерами.

Comment: Из фразы «Grid — это сетка» никак не следует «она размечает КРУПНЫЕ области» и «не подойдёт для верхнего меню»